# Search for string, of certain format; in file name and assign it to variable

Tags: vba

I am downloading files (attachments) from email. I usually have about 10 files in folder `Archive`. (I am processing files and removing them).

Files have different names. However one file always has a name in the format `File XS8456675 2020-11-24`. I am trying to search for this file and assign `XS8456675` to `FileName` variable. `XS8456675` always has two letters in front and numbers after. Also it is hiding between **Word** `space` & `space` **Date**.

Here is my code:

```
Sub findfilename()

    Dim FileInFolder As Object
    Dim objFiles As Object
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    strFolderPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
    Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(strFolderPath & "\Archive\").Files

        For Each FileInFolder In objFiles
    
            If InStr(fso.GetBaseName(FileInFolder), "XS") > 0 Then
                MsgBox ("found")
            End If
    
        Next FileInFolder

End Sub
```

Code seems to be finding file in folder. How to get `XS8456675` from `File XS8456675 2020-11-24` from found file?

Comment: Should I understand that your file name  is composed from three parts, each of them separated by space (" ")? Is that understanding correct? One would be `File`, the other one something like `XS8456675` and the third one like `2020-11-24`. If yes you can use Split function to obtain those strings separated.

Comment: File name is always format `File XS8456675 2020-11-24`. "File" word is always the same and date in the end. Name to be extracted is always between two spaces.

Comment: OK. I will post an answer in some seconds...

Comment: Please test my answer and confirm that this is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the next code:

Declare two new variables

```
Dim strSplit As Variant, strNeeded As String
```

And then replace your existing `For Each FeleInFolder...` with the next one:

```
  For Each FileInFolder In objFiles
     strSplit = Split(fso.GetBaseName(FileInFolder), " ")
     strNeeded = strSplit(1)
     MsgBox strNeeded 
  Next FileInFolder
```

Comment: It should first search for specific file, then split. Otherwise correct!

Comment: @hatman: If I well understood your request, no need of preliminary searching... `fso.GetBaseName(FileInFolder)` returns the file name, then `strNeeded` is directly returned. Only after that you can compare it with whatever you need, I think. Did I wrongly understand your need? Is it necessary to firstly select files containing "XS" or something else? Are there any other files not containing that string which must be escaped from the iteration? Did I wrongly understand anything?

Comment: Code should first search for file with string XS in name (I have more than 10 files in folder), then if file has been found perform your code to that particular file.

Comment: If I place your code inside mine, instead of `MsgBox ("found")` it works as expected.

Comment: OK. You know better what is to be checked... Glad I could help, anyhow.